# Securing ASP.NET MVC Application Checklist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I am looking for a set of guidelines or a checklist that you can go over for securing a public ASP.NET MVC Website. I just want to make sure that I am not making any of the obvious and well known issues when deploying a website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As always, make sure you proper
   encode output - notice that I am
   here saying encode and not
   HtmlEncode. If you're outputting
   content out to HTML then you want to
   use Html.Encode - however if you're
   outputting to JavaScript then you
   want to use a JavaScript encode
   function. - This will help you against Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
2. Use the helpers that help against CSRF attacks where needed (or maybe just everywhere)
3. Depending how you access your data storage, if it's a SQL Database, remember to protect yourself against SQL injections, either through parameterized queries, stored procedures, LINQ or what have you.
4. When you test - make sure your test data contains dodgy output (stuff where a fail to call Html.Encode would reveal itself easily, perhaps through `<script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS attack!");</script>XSS here!`, same goes for stuff that's injected into JavaScript, make mistakes show up!)
5. When model binding use a whitelisting approach for properties so users cannot make the binder bind properties that are not intended to be bound!

Comment: I like item 4.  I don't think enough people do that relying on testers to do those sorts of tests.

Comment: Heh me too, funnily enough this is the sort of thing that came to my mind when I had to think of what piece of advice I would give others - I can now see I need to do some self reflection on some of this...

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at all these comments thinking that I need to do exactly the same.  :)

Comment: Heh you just made my night - glad to know I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 1):

I kinda do the following;

1. Seperate my concerns.  Admin in
   admin folder etc.
2. [Authorize] on all actions that
   require you to be logged in.
3. Html.Encode all data entry fields.
4. ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix =
   "", Exclude = "id")]MyModel
   newModelObject)  <== exclude id's that can be used in an attack

Other than that...

Answer (score 1):

The below are general ASP.NET measures

1. Set Debug=false in web.config
2. Turn on custom error
3. Encrypt your cookies
4. Validate all inputs
5. Enable Request Validation
6. Encode your output

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the default `GET` on actions unless absolutely necessary. For example, if you have a `DeleteUser` action that doesn't have a `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` on it, it can be called via

```
<img src="http://yoursite/admin/DeleteUser/1" />
```

Which will get called by whomever "views" the image.

Comment: IMO If a hacker can inject an img tag into a page, It may not be difficult for him to inject JS which will do a post to the delete url. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, which is why you follow @griegs's advice and [Authorize] sensitive stuff too :). [Authorize] alone won't work, since a user can be logged in (to most apps) without viewing the page.

Comment: Hmm, I got it, exposing GET Request can lead to cross domain XSRF across domain.

Comment: Yeah as mentioned you definatly want to combine this (as in requiring a post, delete or some other header than get) with the anti XSRF helpers - besides that, this is a solid piece of advice.