# What are few tips to secure your Asp.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I want to know what are few things i should test before going live. Basically i want to secure it from hacking threats. Are there some guidelines that i should follow in Asp.Net MVC for securing my website.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168731/securing-asp-net-mvc-application-checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to learn how to use a tool like [burpsuite](http://portswigger.net/burp/), which will automatically check for stuff like sql injection attacks, enumeration attacks, but will probably not check for xss vulnerabilities, and other nasties.

You might also like to buy a book like [web hacking exposed](http://www.webhackingexposed.com/) or [the web application hacker's handbook](http://portswigger.net/wahh/), which demonstrate the techniques that people use to hack websites.

Whilst your application might be very secure/hard to hack, placing it on an unsecured server (especially on shared hosting) might render all your hard work useless.

In the past, I've used third parties to pen-test web applications: if you do this make sure you get a detailed enough report to fix the problems; the ability to talk to someone about any issues they find; some guarantee about re-testing if any issues are found.